# EasyNetQ -- AdvancedBus reconnection

Tags: connection, easynetq

When using `AdvancedBus` for `EasyNetQ`, if the connection is broken up for any reason, how can I reconnect? Does it try to reconnect by itself?

I know `IBus` reconnects itself, but `AdvancedBus` does not seem to do that. For example, if I manually force close the connection using the web management console then the connection is gone forever. And if I recreate the `IAdvancedBus` again I see two new connections.